# How to handle multiple select options submittion in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to submit a form into mongoDB using nodejs API & reactJs. With the exception of the multiple select option, everything is operating as it should be.

Being new to react, I have no idea how to handle the multi select option's onChange method.

Here is what I've tried:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import axios from "axios";
import Select from 'react-select';

export default function EventForm(props) {

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const form = useRef();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [info, setInfo] = useState("");
  const [analysis, setAnalysis] = useState("Undefined");
  const [relatedEvent, setRelatedEvent] = useState([]);


  const handleInfoChange = (e) => {
    setInfo(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleAnalysisChange = (e) => {
    setAnalysis(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleRelatedEvents = (e) => {
    setRelatedEvent(e.target.value)
  }

  const relatedEventsData = props.data.map(opt => ({ label: opt.info, value: opt._id }));

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);

    const eventData = {
      UUID: uuidv4(),
      info: info,
      analysis: analysis,
      relatedEvent: relatedEvent,
    }

    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_PROXY}/api/events`, eventData)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setLoading(false);
        MySwal.fire(
          "Success!",
          "A new event has been saved successfully",
          "success"
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    
  };

  return (
    <div className="panel-body">
      <Form
        ref={form}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className="form-horizontal"
      >
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-6">
            <div className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Info</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter info..."
                {...register("info", { required: true })}
                value={info}
                onChange={handleInfoChange}
              />
              {errors.info && (
                <ul className="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-7" aria-hidden="false">
                  <li className="parsley-required">This value is required.</li>
                </ul>
              )}
            </div>
           
          </div>
          
          <div className="col-lg-6">
            <div className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Related events</Form.Label>
              <Select
                options={relatedEventsData}
                value={relatedEvent}
                isMulti
                onChange={handleRelatedEvents}
              />

            </div>
          </div>
         
          <div className="col-lg-12">
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
              {loading ? "Saving..." : "Save"}
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Could you please guide me how to make it work!
Thank you

Comment: try setting the `state` as ... `setRelatedEvent([...relatedEvent, e.target.value])`

Comment: I did try it but when I select an option from the option list it don't select any value!

Comment: I think the problem is in the <Select  />

Comment: because when I remove  value={relatedEvent} and onChange={handlerelatedEvents} the select option works

Comment: sorry that won't work and need extra code to handle the removal of options .... try the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of Select `onChange` event handler which passes the selected options as an array as argument ..

from that you can `map` over it to get the values as required
something as below:

```
  const handleChange = (opts) => {
    const selectedValues = opts.map((opt) => opt.value);
    setSelectedValues(selectedValues);
  };
```

Please check the working sample for better clarity  -
[image: Edit codesandboxer-example (forked)]

Comment: Did you do same as above ? and while submitting you can submit the `selected` ..